# Proof of LCM property.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, least-common-multiple

I have to prove that $$LCM(a,c)|LCM(ak,cm)$$ For some $k,m \in \Bbb Z$, I've been going around this some time, but cannot come to anything, any help or hint would be great! thanks!

Comment: GCF and GCD mean the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, wrong translation, let me correct.

Comment: Surely any common multiple of $ak$ and $cm$ will also be a common multiple of $a$ and $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $a\mid ak\implies a\mid\operatorname{lcm}(ak,cm)$. For the same reason, $c\mid\operatorname{lcm}(ak,cm)$. Therefore, $\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)\mid\operatorname{lcm}(ak.cm)$.

Comment: I understand how $a|lcm(ak,cm)$ and $c|lcm(ak,cm)$ But i don't get where the therefore comes from. I know this is something really easy to see, but doesn't this prove just that $lcm(a,c)|lcm(ak,cm)$ or $lcm(ak,cm)|lcm(a,c)$?

Comment: @DemianJimenez I just used the fact that$$\alpha\mid\gamma\text{ and }\beta\mid\gamma\implies\operatorname{lcm}(\alpha,\beta)\mid\gamma.$$